# Handling non-AJAX requests on resources that are vey AJAXy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, web-applications

We have several resources that are CRUDed via ajax, ie, inline page reloads with forms and updates. The problem is that some users right-click and open ajax links in a new tab, sending a normal HTML request. This causes all sorts of issues due to non-html handling controllers and views.

IMHO, first prize would be to disable this kind of browser feature so that we don't have to build in allowances for resources and interfaces that are completely ajaxy. But this doesn't seem possible.

What should we do to handle these kinds of requests, given that we have a sizeable application with many ajaxy resources? A massive retrofit is undesirable :(

Comment: The HTML elements that initiate AJAX requests don't need to be clickable links. And if they are, the href parameter does not need to be set to a valid URL.

Comment: Please do not override/disable browser defaults/user preferences. It's horrible when using a website and it doesn't do what I'm expecting